# Abnormal Cpu usage

Tags: kernel, chromium, cpu, process, debian

My computer have **Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU  E5450  @ 3.00GHz** with four real cores.
Sometimes my computer goes really slow but I don't know why. It's not some application run on my desktop, but my chromium and terminal uses sometimes abnormal usage of cpu. Here is the htop list.
[image]

There is nothing special application except shell and chromium. I don't know why my shell sometimes use 120% (now 98.8%) of cpu usage and chromium sometimes use same as shell. On my Tweak tools there is nothing special to be actived.

[image]

edit:  **Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5450 @ 3.00GHz** I buy that CPU secondhand.

edit: Also my fan speed of CPU is average 700rpm.